# Kotlin parameter type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to convert the following Java Code to Kotlin. It compiles and works fine.

```
public abstract class MvpViewHolder<P extends BasePresenter> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected P presenter;

    public MvpViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public void bindPresenter(P presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        presenter.bindView(this);
    }

    public void unbindPresenter() {
        presenter = null;
    }
}
```

In the code I currently have, I get an error on the `presenter.bindView(this)` that states `Required: Nothing, Found: MvpViewHolder`.

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) where P : BasePresenter<*,*> {
    protected var presenter: P? = null

    fun bindPresenter(presenter: P): Unit {
        this.presenter = presenter
        //I get the error here
        presenter.bindView(this)
    }

    fun unbindPresenter(): Unit {
        presenter = null
    }
}
```

`bindView` is defined like so

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<M,V> {
    fun bindView(view: V) {
        this.view = WeakReference(view)
    }
}
```

The only thing I can attribute it to right now is not defining the class generics correctly. As far as I can tell, `this` is still a correct instance of the View generic that is expected as the parameter, I also definitely don't see how it could be `Nothing`. How can I fix the bug?

EDIT: Java code for BasePresenter

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<M, V> {
    protected M model;
    private WeakReference<V> view;

    public void bindView(@NonNull V view) {
        this.view = new WeakReference<>(view);
        if (setupDone()) {
            updateView();
        }
    }

    protected V view() {
        if (view == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return view.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the view variable defined in the BasePresenter class? Can you post the code? `protected var view: V? = null` Is it like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bindView` method requires a `View` as an argument.

The error you're seeing appears when you define a variable (`view` defined on BasePresenter) that can hold a null result or, in your case, a View object.

On the code below you're binding `this` as the argument and MapViewHolder isn't a subclass of View.

```
abstract class MvpViewHolder<P>(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) where P : BasePresenter<*,*> {
    protected var presenter: P? = null

    fun bindPresenter(presenter: P): Unit {
        this.presenter = presenter
        //I get the error here
        presenter.bindView(this) // -> this references MvpViewHolder which isn't a subclass of View
    }

    fun unbindPresenter(): Unit {
        presenter = null
    }
}
```

I think that what you want is to attach the itemView to the presenter because it is in fact a `View` object.

**EDIT**

The problem has to do with defining `BasePresenter<*,*>` which means in this case `BasePresenter<Nothing, Nothing>` (Nothing is an object in kotlin) - read more about **star projections** in kotlin on [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) link.

I would advice defining explicitly the types base presenter is expecting or defining explicitly as `BasePresenter<Any?, Any?>`.

Comment: I looked into that slightly, but realized that it wasn't a problem on the Java side. How come it works with the Java code then?

Comment: @Rafa I think I know what the problem is. I'll update the answer

Comment: @Rafa can you test the proposed answer?

Comment: That worked, it brought up some other errors regarding type parameters extending the BasePresenter<> class, but I think those are out of the scope of this question, and I can fix now that I understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use this to point to current class.

You need to use

`this@class_name` .

For example if "`Example`" is the `class` name, you can use

`this@Example`

It means `this` in Java

For more info visit https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html